# Would time-dependent wave-functions be constrained by relativity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity

Please pardon my beginners understanding.

I was thinking about the wave function of a "free particle",
$\psi(x,t)$, where $\psi(x,0)$ is the initial condition. Writing $\psi (x,t)$ as $\sum\limits_n C_n f_n(x,t)$, where $f_n(x, 0) = \delta(x_n)$. (eg, the superposition of all possible position states).

Would it then be correct to expect the time-evolution of each $f_n(x,t)$ to be $= 0$ when $|x-x_n |> t c$ (eg, must not appear farther away than the speed of light permits)?

Acceptable answers include "that is a stupid question for these reasons...".

Comment: Don't try to force relativity upon standard QM - combining QM and relativity is the realm of quantum field theory, really.

Comment: Okay. I haven't gotten that far yet.

Answer (score 0):

When you write $\psi (x,t)=\sum\limits_n C_n f_n(x,t)$, where $f_n(x, 0) = \delta(x_n)$. Then you are being completely vague.

Because there are many functions $f_n=f_n(x,t)$ such that $f_n(x, 0) = \delta(x_n).$ So you literally have not told us what $\psi(x,t)$ is.

Maybe $f_n(x,t)$ is a standard normal with mean $x_n$ and standard deviation $ct$, maybe it is a standard normal with mean $x_n$ and standard deviation $ct/5000$, we can't tell because you were too vague. And they give different answers for $t=5$ seconds, so you have given two different values of $\psi(x,5$seconds$).$ Which means you haven't really told us what $\psi(x,t)$ is.

Other problems include that you have a sum over $n$ instead of an integral over all positions.

But I'd like to connect what you wrote to standard practice so you can see what people usually do. You might start with very special $f_n$ ones that all by themselves solve Schrödinger's equation. So for instance you might consider $f_k=e^{i(kx-\omega t)}$ where $\hbar^2k^2/2m=\hbar \omega$ and then make $\psi(x,t)=\int \alpha(k) f_k(x,t)dk.$

But these individual waves do move at speed $\omega/k$ which can exceed light speed because the Schrödinger equation is a nonrelativistic equation. Nonrelativistic equations allow unlimited speeds whether they are Newton's equations or Schrödinger's.

I don't know how upset you esnt to get. The equation is just a corkscrew that rotates at a certain angular speed.  Imagine the x axis and then the y and z planes parallel to the yz plane are copies of the complex plane. You select a corkscrew to represent your plane wave, how tight it is wound is related to the momentum and then the whole thing rotates in the yz plane (about the x axis) at an angular frequency $\omega.$ the speed of the wave is how fast along the x axis a particular phase value translates. But firstly, phase velocity is not signal velocity (and neither is group velocity) and secondly the eave is already everywhere and equally strong. And secondly don't read anything whatsoever into the tangential velocity, the overall size (and phase) of the wave is unrelated to anything.

But nonrelativistic theories have huge speeds that's the way things are. And these basic waves are nonzero (and equally sized) everywhere. And if you want a relativistic theory, the most common way (by far) is to wait until you get to quantum field theory.